# How to change the workbench font in visual studio code?

Tags: linux, fonts, visual-studio-code

I want to change the UI font in Visual Studio Code workbench.

I don't mean the editor, but everything else - panels, debug controls, watch, call stack, etc.

Mostly it's because of the Watch, where the values that I'm watching are displayed in an awful font on Debian, where the open/close parentheses aren't symmetrical and it drives me nuts.

Comment: Currently this request is not supported due to extensive code changes and rendering issues if this request is supported.
For more information https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/519

Answer (score 0):

While not being a direct answer to your question, you should check out the following theme repo: https://github.com/wesbos/cobalt2-vscode

The author does change a lot of the elements you're asking for and it appears to be more involved than changing a few lines of CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately that theme in particular doesn't change the font family. And changing a theme is going beyond the scope anyway, as I like my current theme.
But if you're interested in changing the font, maybe my findings (my own answer) will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the system-wide settings on Debian (Gnome) were specifying aliases for fonts, as defined in
`/etc/fonts/conf.d/`

The default monospace font chosen is indeed the most disgusting monospace font out there - Liberation Mono. I identified it by using the new Firefox on a site that had code in it, and seeing the exact same ugly font as in Visual Studio, and Firefox development tools allow font inspection.

Thanks to the discussions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194863/fonts-conf-use-droid-fonts-where-possible/194865) I managed to find the location of the font aliases, and remove any traces of `Liberation Mono`, replacing it with any open source font you might prefer (like Input Mono, Fira Code, Hack, Source Code Pro, etc.)

I found all the config files that I needed to edit using this command:

```
grep "Liberation Mono" /etc/fonts/conf.d/*
```

Then manually replaced (could've done it using `sed` I guess) every occurrence I could find. In my case it was only the following 2 files:

`/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf`
`/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf`

Optionally, I cleared the cache `fc-cache -f`, and tested the solution

```
> fc-match "Courier New"                             
Hack-Regular.ttf: "Hack" "Regular"

> fc-match "monospace" 
Hack-Regular.ttf: "Hack" "Regular"
```

Yay! Refreshing the Firefox page immediately had the desired effect. Completely closing Visual Studio Code and re-opening it had the desired effect.

**But is this a solution to the question?**
Unfortunately no. This is a system-wide change. Although I couldn't be more pleased with the change (Liberation Mono is objectively ugly, with those asymmetrical parentheses), relying on a global change isn't what I had originally asked.
I won't accept this as an answer, but it might help you, dear reader, if you are going through the same suffering as I did with Liberation Mono.

Answer (score 0):

Launch vscode with parameter:

```
> [code or vscode] --disable-gpu
```

GPU hardware acceleration is the default, but sometimes it causes ugly fonts - it causes noises or skews.